# Using LaGrange Multipliers to find a maximum value

Tags: calculus

I'm given the equation $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+3z^2$ with the constraints $x+y+z=1$ and $x-y+2z=2$ and told to find the max and min values using LaGrange multipliers.

I was able to find the maximum value very easily by forming the equations $11\lambda+7\mu=12$ and $7\lambda+17\mu=24$ and using the system of equations to find $\mu=\dfrac{30}{23}$ and $\lambda=\dfrac6{23}$. Plugging these into the original equations gave me $x=\dfrac{18}{23}$, $y=-\dfrac6{23}$ and $z=\dfrac{11}{23}$ which gave me a value of $\dfrac{33}{23}$.

However, this is only one critical point and I'm unsure whether I missed something or if the function truly has only one critical point. Any help on this front would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure what you found is a maximum?

Comment: I believe it is, because I tried (0,0,1) for f(x,y,z) and it yielded a higher value than the one I got with the points above.

Comment: But the word *maximum* means the highest possible value. If you can obtain a higher value, then this is certainly **not** a maximum.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized what I typed. Yes, that is a minimum - which still leaves me stuck as to whether I'm missing a max or it's nonexistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you found is a minimum (of the given function subject to the given constraints). There's no maximum here. And you pretty much already stated the reason — since there's only one critical point, there's only one extreme value (which we determined to be a minimum).

Another way to see that is to look at it geometrically. The two constraints are planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and they intersect on a line. So we evaluate the given function on this line, i.e. at all points $(x,y,z)$ of this line. If we go far away along this line, the absolute values of the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ can become arbitrarily large, and so the values of the given function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+3z^2$ can be arbitrarily large too.

Or the same explanation using numbers rather than geometry. Let $x=100$. Then the corresponding values of $y$ and $z$ that satisfy the constraints (i.e. the coordinates of the corresponding point on that line) can be found from the two equations: $y+z=-99$ and $-y+2x=-98$. Regardless of what we find, the value of the function at this point is at least $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+3z^2\ge x^2=10000$. Picking larger and larger values of $x$ can guarantee that $f(x,y,z$ can grow without a bound.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me! I understand now how the function is able to keep increasing.